# Schedule a command for each users and delete it after that

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I need a way to schedule a command or run a script, which has to be executed just once for each windows users on its next logon.
I.e. If I have 3 users

1. User 1 loggin -> the command is executed and after that deleted.
2. User 2 loggin -> .... the same as the above ...
3. User 1 loggin again -> Just a regular login.
4. Same for User 3.

Comment: There is a registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce` which allows to provide command lines to be executed once only...

Answer (score 2):

You may find this helpful:

[Run and RunOnce Registry Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx)

> By default, the value of a RunOnce key is deleted before the command line is run. You can prefix a RunOnce value name with an exclamation point (!) to defer deletion of the value until after the command runs. Without the exclamation point prefix, if the RunOnce operation fails the associated program will not be asked to run the next time you start the computer.
>
> By default, these keys are ignored when the computer is started in Safe Mode. The value name of RunOnce keys can be prefixed with an asterisk (*) to force the program to run even in Safe mode.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but how can I schedule RunOnce for all other users?

Comment: You can try this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/284193
I couldn't get it to work in windows 10, but it might still under 7.  I don't have a 7 machine handy to test.

Comment: Another option is to have the script check for the thing it is trying to do.  If you can't do that, maybe have the script check for a file in an obscure profile location and if it doesn't exist, make it.  If it does exist, skip the entire batch file so that it doesn't run.  You could also have your script delete itself it if passes the check.  This is how I've done that in the past: `START CMD /C RMDIR /S /Q "%~dp0"`

Answer (score 0):

I found the [solution](https://micksmix.wordpress.com/2012/01/13/update-a-registry-key-for-all-users-on-a-system/). In general - for each user's profile we will have to load its registry hive and to update the RunOnce key. And the link above provides with a script in order to do this automatically. It is same as what is described in the link which is provided by lightwing.

Thanks to everybody.